# Database - Trying to solidify understanding of normalization, how normalized is this?

Tags: database, database-design, database-normalization, 3nf

[I drew an example diagram in Access.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtC2r.png)

[Example SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8aba27)

The relationships and tables fit 3NF:

- a Projects table with fields ProjNumber(PK), ProjName, and ProjDesc
- an Assignments table with compound key consisting of EmpID and ProjNumber, with fields HourlyBillingRate, NumOfHours, and TeamNum
- a Teams table, with fields TeamNum(PK), TeamName, ProjNumber

ProjNumber from Assignments and Teams are foreign keys to Projects and TeamNum from Assignments is a foreign key to the Teams primary key. I don't know if it's necessary to directly reference Teams if I have the ProjNumber foreign key because that project would have an associated TeamNum.

There is a project, a team associated with carrying that out, and employees that are on that team which are paid an hourly billing rate for that project.

I use a compound key to answer "What is the employee works on multiple projects?", so I couldn't make EmpID the sole primary key, thus I chose to make it a compound key because even if the employee works on multiple projects, the combination of the two will always be unique. Each field is necessary and relevant to referenced primary key.

Why does this or doesn't this fulfill 3NF?

Comment: What definition of 3NF are you using & what is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re how are you 1st stuck/unsure applying it? Determining whether NFs are satisfied are faqs. PS Please put what it needed to ask in your post, not just at a link. Please don't repeat code in prose. Please clarify via edits, not comments. [ask] [Help] "Thoughts?" is not an on-topic question.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Your diagram and discussion appear to assume that the primary key is the only candidate key in each of the tables. That appears not to be the case.

In the `Assignments` table, it looks as though `EmpID` and `TeamNumber` is another candidate key, provided that `TeamNumber` may not be NULL.

If we look at this table with `EmpId`, `TeamNumber` as the key, then it is not in 2NF. `ProjNumber` is determined by `TeamNumber`, which is not the whole key.

So now the answer to your question turns on whether FDs are analyzed with respect to all candidate keys or just the declared primary key.  I have seen tutorials on on normalization that go both ways. I follow the one that considers all candidate keys, so the table is not in 2NF.

Unless I've misconstrued the FDs in your case, or `Assignment.TeamNumber` can be NULL.

HOWEVER, your SQL Fiddle presentation is different. Now, if there are several teams on one project, and an employee is assigned to one project for a few hours, there isn't any way to tell what team the employee was on. The FDs are not the same in the SQL Fiddle example and in the implications I take from your diagram.